# iOS8 Keyboard Extension - orientation

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, orientation

I am building a Keyboard Extension for iOS 8, and am trying to deal with device orientation. I have overriddenwillAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation() to modify my layout when the orientation changes, and that works fine, but I have not found a way from the extension to determine the orientation when the view is loaded (each time the keyboard is switched to from another keyboard).

Calling UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation always returns Unknown (at least on the simulator). App Extensions cannot access UIApplication to be able to determine it from there, and the view controller has bounds of 0,0 when viewDidLoad is called.

I am at a loss to discover what the orientation is when the view is loaded. Can anyone help ?

Thanks
Guy

PS I tried overriding viewWillTransitionToSize() but this never seems to get called.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else falls on this issue, here is the solution:-

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
if screenSize.width>screenSize.height { 
  // Landscape 
} else { 
  // Portrait 
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to work for me in iOS 9 for iPads, it does not seem to swap the width and height on device rotation for iPads (It does work for iPhones). Does anyone know how to do this for keyboards on iPads in iOS 9?